# making a check that double type variable should not include alphanumeric string or characters in it

Tags: java, parsing, poi-hssf

I am getting an value which is `double` type so the value would be numeric and can have decimal in it  as shown below

```
Double d = Double.parseDouble((cell.getStringCellValue()))
brokerInvoiceLineItem.setFixedRate(d);
```

So as shown above we are reading a value from the excel sheet that is of string type and then parsing it as double type so the finally the value of this double type can be

```
1.38
1.0725
2,175000
```

now i want to implement a check that value of double type d variable should only be numeric and it can contain float values separated by decimal places but it should not include alphanumeric string that is the value  should not be of type

```
+13.5 BPTS
```

so please advise how can iu put this check before itself

Folks please advise how can I check that double type value should not have any string in it is there any regular expression to check it

Comment: Why are your numbers stored as text cells? Javadoc of [`String getStringCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getStringCellValue%28%29): *"For numeric cells we throw an exception"*. Numbers are stored in *numeric cells*, and must be retrieved using [`double getNumericCellValue()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getNumericCellValue%28%29). No parsing to `double` needed.

Comment: @Andreas agree with you on this but i am getting value in numeric cells also and in string type also so i have handled in both of them the case in which i got stuck is of string type as mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure the string *can* be parsed to a `double` using [`Double.parseDouble(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29), see the regular expression that is provided in the javadoc of [`Double.valueOf(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29):

> To avoid calling this method on an invalid string and having a `NumberFormatException` be thrown, the regular expression below can be used to screen the input string:
>
> ```
> final String Digits     = "(\\p{Digit}+)";
> final String HexDigits  = "(\\p{XDigit}+)";
> // an exponent is 'e' or 'E' followed by an optionally
> // signed decimal integer.
> final String Exp        = "[eE][+-]?"+Digits;
> final String fpRegex    =
>     ("[\\x00-\\x20]*"+  // Optional leading "whitespace"
>      "[+-]?(" + // Optional sign character
>      "NaN|" +           // "NaN" string
>      "Infinity|" +      // "Infinity" string
>
>      // A decimal floating-point string representing a finite positive
>      // number without a leading sign has at most five basic pieces:
>      // Digits . Digits ExponentPart FloatTypeSuffix
>      //
>      // Since this method allows integer-only strings as input
>      // in addition to strings of floating-point literals, the
>      // two sub-patterns below are simplifications of the grammar
>      // productions from section 3.10.2 of
>      // The Java™ Language Specification.
>
>      // Digits ._opt Digits_opt ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
>      "((("+Digits+"(\\.)?("+Digits+"?)("+Exp+")?)|"+
>
>      // . Digits ExponentPart_opt FloatTypeSuffix_opt
>      "(\\.("+Digits+")("+Exp+")?)|"+
>
>      // Hexadecimal strings
>      "((" +
>       // 0[xX] HexDigits ._opt BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
>       "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "(\\.)?)|" +
>
>       // 0[xX] HexDigits_opt . HexDigits BinaryExponent FloatTypeSuffix_opt
>       "(0[xX]" + HexDigits + "?(\\.)" + HexDigits + ")" +
>
>       ")[pP][+-]?" + Digits + "))" +
>      "[fFdD]?))" +
>      "[\\x00-\\x20]*");// Optional trailing "whitespace"
>
> if (Pattern.matches(fpRegex, myString))
>     Double.valueOf(myString); // Will not throw NumberFormatException
> else {
>     // Perform suitable alternative action
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks can you please advise what will be the exact regular expression for that as i am not able to grasp much ,Thanks in advance

Comment: Huh? The javadoc has "the exact regular expression", so I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is much simpler way for this. If you are already using `Double.parseDouble()` then almost your work is done. `parseDouble()` method throws a `NumberFormatException`, if the string input does not contain a parsable double.

So you can wrap the code in `try` block and `catch` the `NumberFormatException` and handle it there.

The code should pretty much look like

```
try{
    Double d  =  Double.parseDouble((cell.getStringCellValue()))
    brokerInvoiceLineItem.setFixedRate(d);
}
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println("Input was not parsable");
}
```